# Broken text after downloading data from website

Tags: c#

So I need to download contents from website and place it on richTextBox. The problem is that when I download contents and filter it using regex, broken text appears. How could I fix it. Below is my code:

```
String website = "https://www.basketnews.lt/news-102294-nba-klubu-vadovai-finalas-nesikeis-mvp-iskovos-jamesas.html";

MyWebClient webClientObj = new MyWebClient();
webClientObj.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
String data = webClientObj.DownloadString(website); 

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(data);

foreach (HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode node2 in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class= 'text']//p")) 
{
  string content = node2.InnerText;
  this.richTextBox1.AppendText('\t' + content + '\n');
}
```

How I want it to look like:

[image: Desktop app with Richtext box with extracted text from the page - expected]

Currently it looks like this:

[image: Desktop app with Richtext box with extracted text from the page - wrong]

Comment: Give an example of the output and compared to the expected output

Comment: do you mean "broken" in the sense of line breaks? set the wordwrap property of the richtextbox to false.

Comment: I see, it is the html entitites

Comment: I would use the [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode(v=vs.110).aspx) method

Comment: The problem is with character encoding

Comment: @user7038346 I think the funny characters are actually fine (what is it, Lithuanian?)

Answer (score 2):

The text contains html-encoded parts. Run it through `HtmlDecode`:

```
var content = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(node2.innerText);
```